# How to create a custom SWT Tooltip using JFACE for an RCP MDirectToolItem?

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface, rcp, e4

I would like to create a custom tooltip for an RCP MDirectToolItem or MHandledToolItem. JFace provides the org.eclipse.jface.window.ToolTip class, which I can extend and override the createToolTipContentArea() method. However, to instantiate a JFace ToolTip, I have to give it the SWT Control that will use the ToolTip. I cannot figure out a way to get the underlying SWT Control from the MDirectToolItem.

I have been able to get the MToolBar and the MDirectToolItem (which I defined in the Application.e4xmi) using the EModelService.find() method. I tried getting the underlying SWT Control from the MDirectToolItem, but it does not appear there is a way to do that.

I also tried creating an SWT ToolItem and adding it to the MToolBar, but the children of the MToolBar are only MToolBarElement's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tool items don't have a separate control, they are part of the parent `ToolBar` control. The SWT `ToolItem` class represents the tool item, this is just derived from `Widget` rather than `Control`.

So you will have to set the tool tip on the tool bar control and work out which tool item is active when the tool tip is shown.

The application model classes which represent UI objects all extend the `MUIElement` interface. This provides a `getWidget` method to get the UI object.

So for `MToolBar` you can do:

```java
ToolBar toolbar = (ToolBar)mtoolbar.getWidget();
```

and for `MToolItem` (either handled or direct) you can do:

```java
ToolItem toolitem = (ToolItem)mtoolitem.getWidget();
```

If you create the `ToolTip` with the `NO_RECREATE` style it will call the 
`getToolTipArea` method to determine if the tool tip need to be changed. You can use something like the following to have a different area for each tool item:

```java
@Override
protected Object getToolTipArea(final Event event)
{
  // TODO save the ToolBar in the class as 'toolBar'
  ToolItem item = toolBar.getItem(new Point(event.x, event.y));
  if (item != null)
    return item;

  return super.getToolTipArea(event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It worked! Storytime: I was working on this issue all day yesterday, and I finally gave up and decided to post a question here. One of my coworkers noticed and asked why I was posting, and I literally replied "I'm hoping that greg-449 will help me." Lol! I appreciate all your well-written answers on SWT, RCP, and JFace stuff. It has helped a lot!